# Is there any flaw in using string as boolean in if statement using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Let's say we have a string:

```
    strTest = "Hello! I am string going to be tested in if statement.";

    if (strTest) {
      document.write("I am string and I am not empty.");
    } else {
      document.write("I am string and I am empty");
    }
```

**Is there any flaw if we use string as Boolean value in if statement?**

Comment: No, if you just know, that any string will be treated as true in `if`, except an empty string.

Comment: Not if you want to test whether a string is empty or not.

Comment: The *else* block will execute if *strTest* is any falsey value, not necessarily an empty string, so the message might be "*If I am a string, I am empty*".

Comment: @RobG ... Could you please write an example to support your point. I think even if there is NULL or FALSE inside double quotes IF statement will be true

Comment: "NULL" isn't a falsey value, `null` is. The point is that you aren't testing exclusively for an empty string, but for any falsey value. If its Type happens to be *string*, then it's an empty string. But if its Type is *number* then it's `0`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know if there is any value in the String

```
if(string)
```

is great.

You get your flaw, if you need to check specifically for an empty undefined or false String.

This is another solution, which tells you exactly wether your String is empty undefined or declared as false.

```
var strTest = "Hello! I am string going to be tested in if statement.";


if (typeof strTest == 'undefined') {
    document.write("I am undefined.");
} else {
    if (strTest == "false") {
        document.write("I am declared as false.");
    } else {
        var length = strTest.length;
        if (length != 0) {    
            document.write("I am string and I am not empty.");
        } else {
            document.write("I am string and I am empty");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Felix, but the question is why I write extra code if the code in question works fine for the purpose? Is there any flaw in the code in question really?

Comment: if `typeof strTest == 'undefined'` then your setting `var length = strTest.length;` raise exception _TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined_